# [Java 1.7.09]GridLayout with guidelines

Tags: java, awt, layout-manager, grid-layout, gridlines

On my JPanel, I've setup GridLayout(10,7). Now this layout does not contain any elements (components). How can grid/guide lines at cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..this layout does not contain any elements (components). How can grid/guide lines at cells?

Put some labels in the cells that have (visible) borders.

> ..One my "Drawing JPanel" is created, it is setup with gridlayout. Then the user selects elements to be displayed. Once the user clicks desired elements, their information are fetched from mysql database and shown in "Drawing JPanel". Before the user selects elements, I already need grid/guidelines and "Align to grid" functionality.

Either put a `JPanel` with a border into the panel.  Or if the grid lines are only temporary until the user puts things in the cell panels:

- Don't put a border on the panel itself.
- Use a `CardLayout`
- Add a label with border.
- When 'real components' are added, add them to the layout and flip the card.

Comment: Well, I cannot do this. One my "Drawing JPanel" is created, it is setup with gridlayout. Then the user selects elements to be displayed. Once the user clicks desired elements, their information are fetched from mysql database and shown in "Drawing JPanel". Before the user selects elements, I already need grid/guidelines and "Align to grid" functionality.

Comment: *"Well, I cannot do this."*  Well you're lucky I'm here, because I ***can.***